# How to use casting with interface?

Tags: java, interface, casting

Why are there following outputs/errors?

```
public class A1 {
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("A1 bar");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A1> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new B());
        /* add the missing lines here*/
    }
}

public interface A2 {
      void foo(List<A1> list, int idx);
} 

public class B extends A1 implements A2 {
    public void foo(List<A1> list, int idx) {
        A1 a1 = list.get(idx);
        if (a1 instanceof B) {
            System.out.println("It's a B!");
        } else {
            a1.bar();
        }
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("B bar");
    }
}
```

1) When adding the following lines to the main:

```
list.add(new A1());
A2 a=(A2) list.get(0);
a.foo.(list,1);
```

Why isn't there a compilation error, since the dynamic type can't be an interface? (the out put is "A1 bar").

2) Why do the following lines lead to a "run time error" but not to a "compilation error"?

```
list.add(new A1());
A2 a = (A2) list.get(1);
a.foo(list, 0);
```

3) Is it correct to conclude that for the following class hierarchy:

```
Interface Animal {...}
class Dog implements Animals {...}
class Poodle extends Dog {...}
class Labrador extends Dog {...}
```

the following line wouldn't compile because the dynamic type is an interface?

```
Animal animal=(Animal) poodle;
```

Comment: basically you're missing `@Override` annotation in `B:foo()` method inherithed from `A2`

Comment: Try to avoid use of `instanceof ` where possible. Use [polymorphism](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm) instead of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why there isn't compilation error, since dynamic type can't be
>   interface? (the out put is "A1 bar").

Something can be an A1 AND an A2 at the same time, for example B. So why should the compiler show an error just because it isn't in that (runtime) situation? `list.get(0);` will return an A1, true, but the compiler has no chance of knowing if it will be an A2, too, or not.

> 2) Why the following lines lead to "run time error" but not to
>   "compilation error"?

Two possibilities, depending on where you add it. Either you are getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException, because the compiler doesn't calculate the size of lists. Why should it? There's a limit to what a compiler should do. In this situation it might be possible to calculate the list size at compile time - but in many other situations it is not and thus it is not the job of the compiler to check stuff like that.

Or you are getting a ClassCastException, because you are getting an A1 object back and try to cast it into an A2. This CAN work, for example if your A1 object was also a B. But in your case, it isn't, just a simple, plain A1 object, which is NOT also an A2. And thus you cannot cast it into one. A Dog MIGHT be a FemaleDog, for example, but it doesn't has to. And if you try to cast a not-FemaleDog into FemaleDog, then you'll get an exception.

> `Animal animal=(Animal) poodle;`

...works perfectly fine, since Poodle is a Dog, which is an Animal, thus Poodle is an Animal.

Comment: Thank you alot!! Can you explain why at the second question there is a "run time error"?

Comment: Ok, that depends on where you put it. Either your list is only of size 1, then get(1) would throw an exception. Or, if that's not the case, then you get your A1 object and try to cast it into an A2. But in this case, your A1 object isn't also an A2 (because it is not a B) and thus that'ss an error.

Comment: list.get(0) is of "B" type, so why casting it into  "A2" is legal- it may "cut off" its extended possibilities?

Comment: In your sample code, you can have two types of objects: A1 objects and B objects. Every B object is also an A1 object and additionall and A2 object. A1 objects are just that, A1. So if you have a list of A1, you can NOT be sure that every object in there is an A2, too, since that's only true for the B objects, but not the "pure" A1 objects.